# Merge two datasets of different sizes

Tags: dataset

I have two data tables formatted as DataSets.

The first one has five keys: `date`, `origin`, `destination`, `type`, `value` (sample below).

```
{<|"date" -> 2008, "origine" -> "Terre-Neuve-et-Labrador", 
  "destination" -> "Terre-Neuve-et-Labrador", 
  "type" -> "produits de base", 
  "valeur" -> 28452.|>, <|"date" -> 2009, 
  "origine" -> "Terre-Neuve-et-Labrador", 
  "destination" -> "Terre-Neuve-et-Labrador", 
  "type" -> "produits de base", 
  "valeur" -> 29029.|>, <|"date" -> 2011, 
  "origine" -> "Ile-du-Prince-edouard", 
  "destination" -> "Nouvelle-ecosse", "type" -> "produits de base", 
  "valeur" -> 305.3|>, <|"date" -> 2016, 
  "origine" -> "Ile-du-Prince-edouard", 
  "destination" -> "Nouveau-Brunswick", "type" -> "services", 
  "valeur" -> 151.5|>, <|"date" -> 2016, 
  "origine" -> "Nouvelle-ecosse", "destination" -> "Quebec", 
  "type" -> "produits de base", 
  "valeur" -> 1327.8|>, <|"date" -> 2009, 
  "origine" -> "Nouvelle-ecosse", "destination" -> "Quebec", 
  "type" -> "services", "valeur" -> 597.2|>}
```

The second on has four keys: `date`, `origin`, `type`, `value` (sample below). This one is very much shorter than the first one.

```
{<|"date" -> 2008, "origine" -> "Terre-Neuve-et-Labrador", 
  "type" -> "produits de base", 
  "valeur" -> 52657.2|>, <|"date" -> 2011, 
  "origine" -> "Ile-du-Prince-edouard", "type" -> "services", 
  "valeur" -> 6738.1|>, <|"date" -> 2013, 
  "origine" -> "Nouvelle-ecosse", "type" -> "services", 
  "valeur" -> 48082.8|>}
```

I am looking to divide `value` of the first dataset by `value` of the second one, while matching the other keys.

Put differently, for each row of the first dataset, I need to find a match for `date`, `origin`, and `type`, and divide the values.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: It looks like your strings aren't properly quoted in your code, which makes it hard to copy-paste. Could you try and add that code again? Also, it's not clear from your comment if you mean `Dataset` the function, or just that you have two datasets, perhaps you could clarify.

Comment: @CarlLange Thank you, is this better?

Comment: What should happen when there is no match?

Comment: @MelaGo There is always a match, due to the structure of the data

Comment: The questions says to find a match for `date`, `origine`, and `type`, but rows 2, 4, 5, and 6 from the first dataset have no match in the second...

Answer (score 7):

```
    ds1 = {<|"date" -> 2008, "origine" -> "Terre-Neuve-et-Labrador", 
    "destination" -> "Terre-Neuve-et-Labrador", 
    "type" -> "produits de base", "valeur" -> 28452.|>, <|
    "date" -> 2009, "origine" -> "Terre-Neuve-et-Labrador", 
    "destination" -> "Terre-Neuve-et-Labrador", 
    "type" -> "produits de base", "valeur" -> 29029.|>, <|
    "date" -> 2011, "origine" -> "Ile-du-Prince-edouard", 
    "destination" -> "Nouvelle-ecosse", "type" -> "produits de base", 
    "valeur" -> 305.3|>, <|"date" -> 2016, 
    "origine" -> "Ile-du-Prince-edouard", 
    "destination" -> "Nouveau-Brunswick", "type" -> "services", 
    "valeur" -> 151.5|>, <|"date" -> 2016, 
    "origine" -> "Nouvelle-ecosse", "destination" -> "Quebec", 
    "type" -> "produits de base", "valeur" -> 1327.8|>, <|
    "date" -> 2009, "origine" -> "Nouvelle-ecosse", 
    "destination" -> "Quebec", "type" -> "services", 
    "valeur" -> 597.2|>};

ds2 = {<|"date" -> 2008, "origine" -> "Terre-Neuve-et-Labrador", 
    "type" -> "produits de base", "valeur" -> 52657.2|>, <|
    "date" -> 2011, "origine" -> "Ile-du-Prince-edouard", 
    "type" -> "services", "valeur" -> 6738.1|>, <|"date" -> 2013, 
    "origine" -> "Nouvelle-ecosse", "type" -> "services", 
    "valeur" -> 48082.8|>};

Divide @@ JoinAcross[ds1, ds2, Key["date"]][[All, "valeur"]]
```

gives 93.1936

Comment: Thank you for your time. I think my question was not clear enough. Ultimately, I don't want a single digit. Right now, in ds1, for every <date>, and every <origine>, I have 12 <destination> and values for each of them. In ds2, for every <date> and every <origine>, I have only one value (not 12). So the goal is to divide, in ds1, every value of same <date> and <origine> by the value of ds2. I don't know If this is clearer? Best

Answer (score 1):

```
data1 = {<|"date" -> 2008, "origine" -> "Terre-Neuve-et-Labrador", "destination" -> "Terre-Neuve-et-Labrador", "type" -> "produits de base", "valeur" -> 28452.|>, 
<|"date" -> 2009, "origine" -> "Terre-Neuve-et-Labrador", "destination" -> "Terre-Neuve-et-Labrador", "type" -> "produits de base", "valeur" -> 29029.|>, 
<|"date" -> 2011, "origine" -> "Ile-du-Prince-edouard", "destination" -> "Nouvelle-ecosse", "type" -> "produits de base", "valeur" -> 305.3|>, 
<|"date" -> 2016, "origine" -> "Ile-du-Prince-edouard", "destination" -> "Nouveau-Brunswick", "type" -> "services", "valeur" -> 151.5|>,
<|"date" -> 2016, "origine" -> "Nouvelle-ecosse", "destination" -> "Quebec", "type" -> "produits de base", "valeur" -> 1327.8|>,
<|"date" -> 2009, "origine" -> "Nouvelle-ecosse", "destination" -> "Quebec", "type" -> "services", "valeur" -> 597.2|>};

data2 = {<|"date" -> 2008, "origine" -> "Terre-Neuve-et-Labrador", "type" -> "produits de base", "valeur" -> 52657.2|>,
<|"date" -> 2011, "origine" -> "Ile-du-Prince-edouard", "type" -> "services", "valeur" -> 6738.1|>, 
<|"date" -> 2013, "origine" -> "Nouvelle-ecosse", "type" -> "services", "valeur" -> 48082.8|>};
```

To get more matches from the sample data provided, I relaxed the match criteria to not include the data (commented out)

```
div = Table[
  match = Cases[data2, 
    KeyValuePattern[{
      (*"date"\[Rule]row["date"],*) 
      "origine" -> row["origine"], 
      "type" -> row["type"]}]];
  If[Length[match] >= 1,
    row["valeur"] = row["valeur"]/match[[1]]["valeur"],
    row["valeur"] = "no match"];
  row,
  {row, data1}]

Dataset[div]
```

[image]